# link wpa_supplicant against non-default openssl version

Tags: linux, openssl, wpa

I want to compile wpa_supplicant using another version of openssl then the one installed on the build system.

To do this, I set these settings in the `.config` file:

```
CFLAGS += -I/custom-openssl/include
LIBS += -L/custom-openssl/lib
```

However, it is still linking against the default installed openssl version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had to set `LIBS_p`. Everything else was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your `-L` directive will be added to the *end* of the list of libraries to look for `.so` files during linking.

Instead, either control which directory the loader should look in while loading the binary (which can be compiled into the binary) or change the list of libraries to search using the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.